Collocation-Based Similarity Score
Given a sequence of numbers I want to calculate a similarity score between the numbers based on the numbers which follow them (collocation frequencies).
Some reservations about the distribution of numbers and expected results:

The numbers distributed logarithmically (in terms of their frequency in the sequence).
I’d like to have a confidence level which is higher when there are more respective collocations (more confirmation of “collocality”) and at the same time not high when very frequent number follows current number (they follow many numbers, so this “following” is not so informative).
I’d like to couple similarity and confidence level in one value, making similarity score less for the less confident cases.
It would be great is the resulting values come normalized, let’s say in range [0,1].

I can calculate basic similarity score as a product of relative frequencies of collocations for specific numbers and frequency itself. This gives good result for the score.
Hard times come when I want to introduce confidence level (could be considered as weight) here. I can’t figure out the formula which will be robust to the size of the set and high/low frequent numbers.
I assume that I should multiply by number of collocations and divide by amount of numbers in the sequence which participate in collocations, but I can’t end up with the robust formula. With this I mean that I assume that if numerator and denominator chosen correctly, the formula should be robust to any frequency deviations and should be self-normalizing (without any extra measures like sigmoids, etc.).
In most cases the result is strongly biased by frequency of numbers of interest or collocated numbers.
What this formula should look like and what is the basics for getting the intuition behind it?
I read some articles on the subject like An Information-Theoretic Definition of Similarity, but they use more sophisticated models and hard to follow.
I am quite sure that this is very basiс statistics/probability theory question and I am missing very simple solution here. Could you please help me figure out it?
